# To check an integer more than 0

Tags: java, integer

I have the following setter:

```
public void setId(String id) {
        try{
            Integer partnerId = Integer.parseInt(id);
            if (partnerId <= 0){
                throw new NumberFormatException();
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){ 
        }
        this.id = id;
    }
```

Is it a good way to check if the passed argument is an integer more than 0?

Comment: An `IllegalArgumentException` would suffice?

Comment: Why are you catching the exception that you just throw and doing nothing with it?

Comment: is it any reason why you keep your id as string? second thing, as you are handling exception which you are throwing, your check is redundant

Comment: Actually, the best way to handle it will change depending of what you have to do when the integer is not greater than 0. If you don't tell us, we can't really give a good answer, so I'll flag the question as too broad. What is clear is that the code in your question makes no sense, because you can just delete  all the try / catch block and the code inside and the result would be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't throw a NumberFormatException, because there was nothing wrong with the format if the string - it was simply out of range. The standard, and correct, exception to throw is IllegalArgumentException with a message. And as a general rule (which applies here), you shouldn't catch an excrotion, but do nothing with it.

Try this:

```
public void setId(String id) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(id) < 1){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("id must be greater than zero:" id);
    }
    this.id = id;
}
```

Also:

- removed the int variable since you don't use it exception for comparing
- removed the try catch - just let the exception bubble out. If the client passed bad dara that's their problem

Answer (score 3):

[`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) states:

> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a
>   string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have
>   the appropriate format.

That's not the situation in your case, if you insist to throw an exception, implement your own class:

```
public class LowerThanZeroException extends Exception {
    public LowerThanZeroException() { super("Number is lower than zero"); }
}
```

Or simply use [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html).

I don't think `try` and `catch` is the best option for you (although this really depends on your logic), but consider using `if` statement as well.

Also note that catching an exception and doing nothing with it will actually hide the problem.

Comment: So how to check that in the right way?

Comment: I mean maybe regexp is gonna be better here?

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom exception for `(partnerId <= 0)` condition. but do catch number format exception as well because you might be trying to convert a string to integer. but if you just want to check if the number is less than zero or not, you can do it in `if statement`. No need to throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to to this is using an if statement

```
public void setId(String id) {
        Integer partnerId;
        try{
            partnerId = Integer.parseInt(id);
        } catch(Exception e){ /*if parsing fails do ...*/ }
        if (partnerId <= 0){ this.id = /*some default value*/ }
        else {this.id = id;}
}
```